# Cordova 3.4.0, how to Media.setVolume()?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, media

I've added sounds to my Cordova app (`3.4.0`), but I can't set the volume unless I play the sound.

Here is the code to make it works :

```
var myMedia = new Media("file:///android_asset/www/sounds/button.mp3");
myMedia.play();
myMedia.stop();
myMedia.setVolume("0.2");
```

I tried the below code, but it isn't working too :

```
var myMedia = new Media("file:///android_asset/www/sounds/button.mp3", function() {
    this.setVolume("0.5");
});
```

Do you have another clean method ?

Comment: When you say you can't set the volume, do you mean that it plays at full volume initially before going down to 0.2?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The first solution works but sometimes the app doesn't stop and plays the entire sound...

Comment: Your example is the only way I can set the volume also.

Answer (score 2):

I set the volume to 0 before playing then incrementally increase it to the required volume. But you shouldn't need to bother with the fade in. Something like this should work:

```
mediaPlayer = new Media(localSoundsPath + sound_file_name);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0);
mediaPlayer.play();
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2);
```

Comment: That's worst because I'll need to call `mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2);` after each call to make sure it will apply. In fact, I use my media several times in my app :/
But maybe I should create a function that plays the sound.

Comment: I don't see how this is worse than your original code, and it should solve your stated problem of initially playing the sound at full volume. You will need to set the volume every time you create a media player, and when you've finished playing a sound, you should think about disposing of it to free up resources if you're not going to be playing the sound again soon, etc. So yes, creating a function to play the sound and set the volume is a good idea.